# How to store long range number

Tags: java

I have to store this value.but eclipse shows error on that.

```
private final long cal_To_eV = 26131952998320000000L;
```

plz tell me how to store this.

Comment: have you tried anything? please tell us about what you've tried.

Comment: the literal is to long for type "long" that's all...

Comment: long : -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the class [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: add a link to oracle docs? :)

Comment: i also tried that..but not working...still shows error

Comment: You're right :D.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/class-use/BigInteger.html

Comment: BigInteger bigInteger2 = new BigInteger ("26131952998320000000"); 
works for me...

Comment: can i store this without creating any object... means i have to write this as i wrote above.

Comment: no, the literal is to long for the type "long"...

Comment: i am converting calorie to electronVolt..so it can't taken as string.

Comment: then i assume you have to use BigInteger or BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String` not `long`. Also you can use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [BigDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

```
private final BigInteger cal_To_eV = new BigInteger("26131952998320000000");
```